# Extra unwanted text displaying from a woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

On my homepage I have a plugin displaying 'Product Of The Day' but for some reason the Review information from the current featured product from the single product page keeps appearing at the bottom of the home page main content.

> Reviews
>
> There are no reviews yet.
>
> Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to remove it?

The Product Of The Day is being displayed on the homepage with the shortcode:

```
[br_products_of_day title=”Product Of The Day” add_to_cart=”true” thumbnails=”true”]
```

Thanks

http://ediblecaketoppers.ie

UPDATE:

I have removed Reviews from the site until a solution can be found but this here is a screenshot of the issue i'm having...

[Review text that is showing from the 'The Product Of The Day' further up the home page...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6TAv.png)

Comment: Possibly the issue is with the plugin or may be plugin is supposed to be in displaying those info Did you check with the plugin author ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to functions.php and Add the following code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_reviews_tab', 98);

function woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) { 
    unset($tabs['reviews']);
    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: I have a white screen now i've tried removing it from functions through my hosting file manager but still white screen...

Comment: home page is a template?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: home page is custom template?